# Login and set remember_me cookie after user registration in Symfony

Tags: symfony, symfony4, symfony-security

I have a controller action which processes user's data, registers the user, logs them in and redirects them to another controller's action. However I am unable to get the "remember_me" cookie set.

On a successful registration, the controller will obtain the **$user** object and then pass this onto the **authenticateUserAndHandleSuccess()** method of the **GuardAuthenticatorHandler** which is part Symfony's Security Bundle.

```
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use App\Security\LoginFormAuthenticator;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Guard\GuardAuthenticatorHandler;


public function register(Request $request, LoginFormAuthenticator $authenticator, GuardAuthenticatorHandler $guardHandler) {

    // do something... and get $user object

    return $guardHandler->authenticateUserAndHandleSuccess(
        $user,
        $request,
        $authenticator,
        'main'
    );

}
```

What this does is to automatically login the user. However, it does not set the remember_me cookie which is presently working and used in the login form.

From the security.yaml

```
    remember_me:
        secret: '%kernel.secret%'
        lifetime: 2592000 # 1 month in seconds
        path: /
        remember_me_parameter: login_form[_remember_me]
```

How could the controller be changed to also set the "remember_me" cookie?

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if this is a good idea to set `remember_me` during registration but if you really need it just check [onLoginSuccess](https://github.com/symfony/security/blob/master/Http/RememberMe/TokenBasedRememberMeServices.php#L70) method of `TokenBasedRememberMeServices` which is executed during `login` process when proper `remember me` parameter is being send - it's just about setting proper cookie.